# Redirect to homepage is user is not a member of the site permissions Owner group

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

How can I write the following in JavaScript?
in SharePoint 2019, if a user who is not a member of the site permissions Owner group is immediately redirected to the homepage...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is JavaScript library that provided a easy way to check user's group membership:

- [GetGroupCollectionFromUser](https://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/core/web-services/UserGroup/GetGroupCollectionFromUser.html)

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
 $().SPServices({
  operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
  userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
  async: false,
  completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
  var xml = xData.responseXML.xml;
 
   //If the current User does belong to the group "Service desk Operators"
    if (xml.search('Service Desk Operators') != -1)
     {
          //   do your logic          
     }   
    }
 });
});
```

Other references or demos:

- [Check if current user is in a specified group Using SPServices](https://www.splessons.com/check-if-current-user-is-in-a-specified-group-using-spservices/)